# SQL query error 'Subquery returned more than 1 value...' for DELETE FROM IN

Tags: sql

Query:

```
DELETE FROM [dbo].[Time] 
WHERE UserId IN (SELECT Id FROM [dbo].[Users] WHERE Name like 'test')
```

sql error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
> subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
> an expression.

Others advise to use IN instead of = but query already uses IN

This happens if [dbo].[Time] have 2 and more rows with the same UserId

Query looks legit, maybe someone knows what can the problem?

Comment: in subquery add `DISTINCT` to find unique USERID.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that clause, there's something you're not sharing. Can you reproduce it in a DB<>Fiddle.

Comment: Is there a delete trigger on `dbo.Time`?

Comment: Must be some trigger that is written as if users only delete one row at a time.

Comment: dbo.Time has one trigger in Triggers folder. @Shannon Severance

Comment: The error is most likely in that trigger code. Becuase the delete statement in your question would not result in that error.